# Is it possible to develop WebRtc for android using Windows?

Tags: android, webrtc

I am new to `WebRtc` Development in Android.I am developing currently on `Windows 7`.I referred [this](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android) link but it says `Android development is only supported on Linux`.But when I referred [this](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development) it says that developemnt is supported on windows too. I am unable to find `OpenJDK` for windows.

Can anyone tell me can I develop webrtc for android using windows?

Comment: The question is this, do you want to access the WebRTC source code or simple develop an android application using WebRTC(not modify WebRTC itself)?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I want to first test the WebRTC source code and then develop an android application using WebRTC

Comment: You can only develop on windows using the precompiled native WebRTC library. At least without significant effort